# Fastest iteration priority

Tags: iteration

Which is fastest/safest way to iterate through two nested loops? Or are both the exact same?

- Iterate through 6 skus, load 200 products to find a match.

  for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
  {
    for ( j = 0; j < 2000; j++ )
    {
      if ( j->sku == i->sku ) break;
    }
  }
- Load 200 products, iterate through 6 skus to products to find a match.

  for ( i = 0; i < 2000; i++ )
  {
    for ( j = 0; j < 6; j++ )
    {
      if ( j->sku == i->sku ) break;
    }
  }

Comment: If you have the code written, why not test it and tell us the answer?

Comment: What is `i->sku` if `i` is integer?

Comment: Heh. That's actually pretty funny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unroll the loop that is looping for 6 times because it is wasting time. Or keep it as outer loop because you dont want the local variables to be exchanged for every 6-iterations.